# NetInfo removed from React Native error even after upgrading to 'react-native-community/netinfo'

Tags: react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

> Invariant
>   Violation: NetInfo has been removed from React Native. It can now be
>   installed and imported from 'react-native-netinfo' instead of
>   'react-native'

Getting the above error even after updating `react-native-netinfo` to `react-native-community/netinfo`. I have also changed the imports to `import NetInfo  from '@react-native-community/netinfo';`

[image]

Comment: perhaps one of your dependencies still imports it from `react-native`?

Comment: @azundo How can I fix it?

Comment: If you expand the error stacktrace in the console you might be able to see the source file that the error is originating from which. Alternatively search your `node_modules` for `NetInfo` - (e.g. `cd node_modules && grep -R NetInfo .` on MacOS for example) to find the dependency that is using `NetInfo` from `react-native` then upgrade or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the packager, remove your **node_modules** folder, and reinstall the packages `yarn install`, and then restart the packager.